# creating an event in mysql to insert and select data

Tags: mysql, sql

I working on attendance management system, I am storing punch in and punch out timings of  employees in a table on a button click, Now I want to store data in the same table when an employee is absent, I am thinking to insert 00:00:00 or null values on event which will occur at 12pm everyday ,It will check whether every employees' id present in attendance table for today's date, if not it should enter an absentee i.e. 00:00:00 or null for punch in and punch out time, can anyone guide me to create this event?
  I tried

```
CREATE EVENT e_daily
    ON SCHEDULE
      EVERY 1 DAY

    DO
      BEGIN
        INSERT INTO attendance(e_id,punch_in,punch_out)
          SELECT e_id
            FROM attendance;
          where punch_in != CURDATE
      END
```

But showing an error meassage

Comment: why not use null instead?

Comment: Why store that at all?

Answer (score 0):

One of the reasons for the error is you're only inserting one value (as defined in the SELECT) when the INSERT is expecting three. Another issue is that you've ended the statement **;** and then written a WHERE clause on the next line which isn't part of the statement.

Using case you can insert a NULL entry when the punch in date is not the current date. Code included below;

```
INSERT INTO 
    attendance(e_id,punch_in,punch_out)
SELECT 
    e_id, 
    CASE
        WHEN punch_in != CURDATE
        THEN NULL
        ELSE punch_in
    END punch_in,
    CASE
        WHEN punch_in != CURDATE
        THEN NULL
        ELSE punch_out
    END punch_out 
FROM 
    attendance;
```